# Checking battery status using other than acpi command

Tags: 11.10, battery, acpi

Is there any way to get the battery status without **`acpi`**?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and I needed to install `acpi` via **`apt-get`**. So I guess there's another command that is used to check battery status rather that **`acpi`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state` in a terminal. Alternatively, change the `state` to `*` to display all info in that directory.